# angular 4 how to use skipLocationChange with a href

Tags: angular, href

I have a,  tag, with href. I don't want to change the URL when this link is clicked but still traverse to where it should be. I saw that we can use 
skipLocationChange, but not working. Any alternatives suggested.

In my html:

```
<a href="#/temp" skipLocationChange>linkitem</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `[routerLink]` directive to access that property

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

```
<a [routerLink]="['/temp']" skipLocationChange>linkitem</a>
```